# Change the colour of the title of a SharePoint 2013 page

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, pages, title

I have been able to indent the title of the SharePoint page, change the font size and font type but cannot change the colour of the title. This is my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #pageTitle
  {    
  text-indent:48px;
  font-size:36pt;
  font-family:"Comic Sans MS"
  }
  </style>
```

I have tried adding the following code in between the { and }:
color:red;
color:red !Important;
color:html code
color:html code !Important;
and then font-color:
and text-color;
with the above combinations.
Nothing changes the text colour.
I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Not all of the code came through.  The first part is <style type="text/css">and ends with </style>

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #pageTitle a
  {    
  text-indent:48px;
  font-size:36pt;
color:red!important;
  font-family:"Comic Sans MS";
  }
  </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `<style>`

```
#pageTitle span a {
    color: red;
}
```